# Inappropriate dating ad on The Workplace

Tags: support, advertising, inappropriate-advertisements

The drill is getting old, here is today's "inappropriate ad" report, this time on The Workplace, possibly elsewhere.

It's in French, translation left for the reader as an exercise.

> [image: inappropriate ad]

```
https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/aclk?sa=l&ai=CLp1c7w6eXeeCHtD8bMfYu6AKuIX_qFb76J-p4gf0kMj7mgIQASDVqYErYPv5_IKICqAByLOU-wLIAQKpAo1gQwYnbbI-4AIAqAMByAMIqgTJAk_QHbnMCFfDz_2fBrJDK8aOuBX_FSuuEYmxweb_Xo3B3B1Ptu84TGST43-rkZx21_pi14QdgzrLHmnBMfVEDcjQxKInMp-s1qvvaFNAk46uTqrBTDnMpbkYz1FSflgYBbuxaYF4VIrV9u03GV1MkQtuWROWrsuhGsNmwewKKLoVjIviGqMQDtdR9B2LwNj-YYkhJtEoxOIiLJMSueVfS_IFzdcV9bS8dxAW37CVVhqIh7QsVSf9XTZA8GrH4ADfgNqgDaac4euPg1mhlIaPS6C8P4IjXFNdfq7v-mhHIw_fag2SF6gDq2Y_qV1_SBR4cWEVmU2izZqqIYtyDQ_8MzQxFEN31U0bqrhC4zjXkTwhP8THTlBFjii6g560MWMhizu68jJ-Clf2QCakho9mNnM4D5jCOLWQ1FAZ3-BkBd6_3ZzYM2DsZ8r1wAT5tuOy6AHgBAGIBbTF5tsFoAYC2AYCgAegzOuEAagHjs4bqAfVyRuoB8HTG6gHhdQbqAeB1BuoB4LUG6gHhtQbqAeE1BuoB5PYG6gH4NMbqAe6BqgH2csbqAfPzBuoB6a-G6gH89EbqAfs1RvYBwGgCI60PbAIAtIICQiA4YAQEAEYHfIIG2FkeC1zdWJzeW4tNTk5OTk1OTE2MTY1OTgyMbEJmEl5CJasoD-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&ae=1&num=1&sig=AOD64_0hj1wTqiWaRWlsAWtBEQ_rHgIfRw&client=ca-pub-2024690810381654&nx=CLICK_X&ny=CLICK_Y&nb=2&adurl=https://m.tendermeets.com/ppc.php%3Fdynamicpage%3Dtm_mlp_5st_memb_t%26utm_source%3Dppc%26utm_medium%3Dmob%26utm_campaign%3Dcontent%26utm_term%3Dfra%26text%3Ddating%26utm_campaignid%3D1534698164%26ppc_cp%3D3000000015%26clkid%3DEAIaIQobChMIp7aXu9CP5QIVUD4bCh1H7A6kEAEYASAAEgK0avD_BwE%26utm_campaignid%3D1534698164%26%26gclid%3DEAIaIQobChMIp7aXu9CP5QIVUD4bCh1H7A6kEAEYASAAEgK0avD_BwE
```

Comment: Interesting, we saw [something similar on Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14644/how-can-i-report-nsfw-ad-on-main-site) recently

Comment: I guess "inclusivity" and being kind and courteous means allowing all people who objectify women (especially who pay to promote that idea) to do so on our network.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for reporting the ad. It is now blocked from our network.  Additionally, it goes against our ad policy.

[image: screenshot showing that the ad has been blocked]

Comment: What is this "report ad" button? Is it something deployed on Stack Exchange very recently and I can't see it because I'm on mobile, or is it something you (staff) can see on your end because you have setting rights or something?

Comment: Nevermind, didn't notice the "dismiss" cross. Still - do ads I report to Google automatically get banned from your lists as well?

Comment: I'm gonna ask again: what system are you using? It's failing at an increasing rate, and for a network that serves millions of people where meta participation is low percent-wise, a lot of these risk going unnoticed. The system matters - a failing one risks being directly damaging to SE, and not to forget the community.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but how does anyone know what violates Google's ad policy, and why would that be applicable or relevant to SE sites?  For example, tasteful underwear ads would be appropriate in some places and not violate Google policy, but would be inappropriate here.  Users acting as the filter for SE and needing to report every inappropriate ad will get old fast.  In general, irrelevant ads, even if not offensive, give SE an unprofessional image.

Comment: what I hate about these ads (and why you are making big mistake relying on reporting provided by Google) is that f#cking option to report ad as inappropriate sometimes is not f#cking available.It just happened that I stumbled over a page on one of SE sites which had three ads, two were NSFW ads and one was not of the kind worth reporting. And guess what, option to report inappropriate was available to me only on the ad that didn't need it - both ads serving f#cking NSFW had list of reporting options that didn't include inappropriate. And it's not the first time I observe this. F#cking annoying

Comment: Y'know, ads are going to backfire if you don't get a handle on it.  You're alienating most of your potential audience by dropping the ball this badly, which will negate the reason you're displaying ads in the first place.  Although, I suppose UBlock and Adblock are very happy with this turn of events...

Comment: uBlock Origin is worth it.