# Reporting ads as off-topic / irrelevant based on the site scope

Tags: discussion, advertising

I usually do not pay attention to ads but lately I've noticed that most of the ads on Web Applications that are shown to me are related to developing web applications but that is off-topic on the site as it scope is about **using** web applications. If ads are inevitable I would like to see "on-topic" ads.

I know that ads could be reported as inappropriate but is it possible to "flag" ads as off-topic?

Notes:

- The [advertising guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/advertising/guidelines) doesn't mention that ads should be on-topic.
- According to [Affiliate Ads Are Coming To The Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306737/289691), a post from 2018, ads were hand-picked, so it's very likely that "the hand" will appreciate the feedback. Actually it also says that ad feedback should done on the corresponding per-site meta but doesn't include any specific guideline i.e.  what tags mandatory / regular tags should be used.
- From the [current top answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335431/289691)  to [What sort of ads should SE managers accept?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335426/289691)

  > How could Stack Exchange get me to unblock ads: a wish list. ...
  >
  > - Ads should have some relevance to the site I am on. I am fine if Arqade gets videogame ads, I don't need kitchen knifes ads on SharePoint, an I don't feel the need for Snake-Oil advertisement anywhere on the network.
- From [We're testing advertisements across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329763/289691), a post from 2019

  > If you see any ads that are inappropriate or have any questions about this experiment, please let me know by starting a new question and tagging it with [advertising](/questions/tagged/advertising).

  As you can see the above quote doesn't mention irrelevant ads.

Below one example of irrelevant ads

> [image]
>
>  Translation: Learn new skills and continuedly experiment with Azure.

The above ad is promoting a cloud platform to developers / sys-admins. It was shown on a question about using cached pages in Google (google-search) as well on unrelated questions.

Related

- [What sort of ads should SE managers accept?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335426/289691)
- [Report this Ad Feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345476/289691)

Comment: I mean...if I were writing an ad-targeting algorithm, someone with 366 Stack Overflow posts in the JavaScript tag wouldn't be a _bad_ choice of target for web-application development ads, even though in your case it's less apt since they're nearly all Google Apps Script.

Comment: @RyanM In 2018 ads were hand-picked (see the link I added few minutes ago). I'm wondering if they still are hand-picked.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [Ads on SE sites are excessively animated, irrelevant, dubious and resource-intensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329547/289691), a post from 2019, as that Q/A make emphasis on ads that affect site's performance but as of August 15th, 2021, I haven't noticed that problem.

Comment: Why put the ad in a spoiler tag?

Comment: @BSMP To reduce the ad displaying in the question body.